# Need help in creating multiple lists from one query in Apex Class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I am trying to achieve a list like this

```
(conWrapper:[BankName=abcd, Branch=main, phone=123456789],
 conWrapper:[BankName=abcd, Branch=main, phone=987654321])
```

From below class,

```
public without sharing class SendData{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Object processData(string contId) { 
        if(String.isNotBlank(contId)){              
            List<Contact> con = [Select BankName__c, Branch__c, Phone1__c, Phone2__c from contact where id =: conid];
            
            List<reqWrapper> conWrapper = new List<reqWrapper>();
            for (Contact c : con){
                reqWrapper r = new reqWrapper();                
                if(String.isNotBlank(c.Phone1__c)){
                    r.BankName = c.BankName__c;
                    r.Branch = c.Branch__c;
                    r.phone = c.Phone1__c; //123456789
                    conWrapper.add(r);
                }
                if(String.isNotBlank(c.Phone2__c)){
                    r.BankName = c.BankName__c;
                    r.Branch = c.Branch__c;
                    r.phone = c.Phone2__c; //987654321
                    conWrapper.add(r);
                }
                                
            }            
        }
        return conWrapper;
    }

    public class reqWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled public string BankName;
        @AuraEnabled public string Branch;
        @AuraEnabled public string phone;
    }
}
```

but this is what I am getting

```
(conWrapper:[BankName=abcd, Branch=main, phone=123456789],(already output))
```

Can someone help me here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reusing the same "instance" of your object in memory. You can think of an instance like a box. You can only put one value in the box, and if you put in another one, you'll have to remove the old value first.

You need to create a new object for each row.

```
            if(String.isNotBlank(c.Phone1__c)){
                reqWrapper r = new reqWrapper();                
                r.BankName = c.BankName__c;
                r.Branch = c.Branch__c;
                r.phone = c.Phone1__c; //123456789
                conWrapper.add(r);
            }
            if(String.isNotBlank(c.Phone2__c)){
                reqWrapper r = new reqWrapper();                
                r.BankName = c.BankName__c;
                r.Branch = c.Branch__c;
                r.phone = c.Phone2__c; //987654321
                conWrapper.add(r);
            }
```

Comment: how did I miss that, that worked! thank you so much @sfdxfox!!